# Hide warnings on OPA development interview screen

Tags: oracle, policy, oracle-apps

[Oracle Policy Automation](https://www.oracle.com/applications/oracle-policy-automation/) shows warnings on an interview development screen. The warnings are not relevant. How to hide the warnings? I know it is possible.

Tried right click on the warning with every possible key combination (Ctrl-Alt...)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set checkbox "warning level"(Waarschuwingsniveau toegankelijheid - ductch)  to Geen (dutch) on stylesheet screen.

[image]